# What are possible non-code-related reasons for a blank screen in Flash Builder 4.6 Design View?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

I was editing a very basic mobile Flex project, and after I debugged the master (application) mxml file, **Design View stopped working** (blank screen displayed, no Design View errors) **for all files**. Creating new projects, either mobile or else, or testing old, working projects, doesn't work either. Out of the related issues I've found info on, most concern earlier versions of the IDE, and deal with either Design View errors (got none), use of certain functions or custom components (I get the error even on a new project), or are solved by changing styles back-and-forth (tried already, to no avail).

**I can't drag and drop components to the design area**, either (a "prohibited" symbol appears and nothing happens when I drop); **so I'm pretty sure it's not code-related** or a bug, but **probably something stupid**, like a configuration issue, so I definitely need someone to take a fresh look at it.

So, ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your app still run / work with no issues?

Comment: App worked fine, it was just the Design View that didn't.
 
Situation's still the same. Now I'm working at a company that doesn't really use Flex, so I'm taking a break from playing with it, didn't really have time to look for a solution.

Comment: Design view is very buggy and only works with a specific version of Flex; related to the version of Flash Builder you have installed.  Most devs don't use it b/c of such issues.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pity though, I planned to use it to help non-devs contribute, which I believe is the reason Design View exists, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and am interested in a solution. I can't design any mobile applications in FB 4.6. The design view area is just white (no errors message like I've seen before) and I can't drag any components into the area.

The application does run without errors though. It just doesn't show anything in the design view.
Even something as simple as this is not editable in design mode:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<components:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                 xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                 xmlns:components="spark.components.*" 
                 title="Home">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</components:View>`
```

So, it's not a coding problem. It probably has something to do with the 4.6 SDK. I will try using a 4.5 SDK and see what happens. But, I want to make use if the 4.6 SDK though.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that kind of simple code too, and I've seen other people around who have got the same problem and just gave up on the Design View feature. It's a shame though, hope Adobe fixes it up in time for next release.